# SQL Server - schedule a one-time task to run after a currently running task finishes?

Tags: sql-server

I'm running a stored procedure right now that will likely take 12 hours to complete, however the exact actual time is unknown.  I have another stored procedure that I need to run once the currently running one is finished.  Is it possible in SQL Server to schedule something to run, one time, e.g. "after dbo.storedProcedureName completes execution"?

Yesterday I tried the schedule option in SQL Server Agent called "Start whenever the CPU's become idle" but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with some add-in, or with a loop monitoring running processes, but it isn't really the best way. Instead, you should set up an SQL Script to run the two in sequence, e.g.:

```
EXEC dbo.MyLongRunningProc;
EXEC dbo.MyOtherProc;
```

These are guaranteed to run in sequence, one right after the other, when run from inside SSMS or a similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and execute (or schedule) a procedure that runs both

```
create procedure runBothInOrder
as
begin tran
exec procedure1
exec procedure2
commit
```